# Seaside/Smalltalk - how to highlight a row in a table?

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

Is there currently a way to highlight a row in a table? For example, I would like to list a table of entries and be able to highlight a row and click **Process**. I can't find any examples of this online - I'm sure there's a way though, right?

Highlighting the row could be done based on a radio button - a user selects the radio button for the row they want to update, and then click **Process** or whichever button they want, and that action would be performed for that row.

Any help on where I should look (or just a quick example) would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use a radio button, try add a jQuery action on it.

Something like:

```
onClick: ((html jQuery: #tableRowId) toggleClass: 'highlight')
```

Then have CSS that'll highlight the row

```
.hightlight {
     background-color:light-yellow
}
```

If you need a more extensive example, let me know.

Comment: Not that anything is wrong with Dusty's suggestion, but I would even try to avoid having to put an id into the expression.

Without having tried, I suggest using:

onClick: ((html jQuery closest: 'tr') toggleClass: 'highlight')

Comment: @JoachimTuchel has years more experience than I do and I've often been aided by his comments in the VAST realm.  I've actually used the closest: 'tr' before, and it works well.